# Telegram bug on WithRequestContact, how solve or get round this issue?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I identify user by his number, but suddenly noticed when send other contact number, [message.Contact] is not empty. I want remember what dialog answered. But ios data is differ from android. As I understand on ios you can not differ own number from other attachment contact. How get around this problem?

```
     if (message.Contact != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Contact.PhoneNumber))
        {
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
           if (message.ReplyToMessage!=null) // when send own contact on ios always null there, on android not null
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
              {
                 if (message.ReplyToMessage.Text == "Отправка тел.номера")
                     {
                       var phone = message.Contact.PhoneNumber;
                       botLogMessage.AppendLine(phone);
                       if (phone.Length >= 9)
                          {
                             RegistrateUserPhoneNumber(message);
                          }
                    }
                else if (message.ReplyToMessage.Text == "Укажите телефон")
                        {
                          //
                        }
                 }
    }
        
            private void RequestPhoneNumber(string command, long chatId)
            {
                 StringBuilder botLogMessage = new StringBuilder();
                 botLogMessage.AppendLine(command);
                 var messageText = "Отправка тел.номера";
                 botLogMessage.AppendLine(messageText);
                 botLogsService.SendTextMessageAsyncWithRequestContact(chatId, messageText, replyMarkup: new ReplyKeyboardRemove());
            }
                    
                    
             
            public async Task<Message>  SendTextMessageAsyncWithRequestContact(long chatId, string messageText,  IReplyMarkup? replyMarkup)
            {
              KeyboardButton button = KeyboardButton.WithRequestContact(messageText);  // Right here, the string defines what text appears on the button
            ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(button);
             return await telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, messageText, replyMarkup: keyboard);
            }
```